# Mozilla Thunderbird Addon - Add icon to message header

Tags: xul, thunderbird-addon

I would like to add an icon/button next to reply button in MOZILLA THUNDERBIRD. What should I write in XUL file so that icon in message header will be shown?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Building_an_Extension which applies to Firefox, but is largely valid for Thunderbird. Once you get to the part where you're supposed to overlay the interface, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Building_an_Extension to figure out that you need to look up msgHdrViewOverlay.xul http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mail/base/content/msgHdrViewOverlay.xul . Use the https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/6622/ DOM inspector addon to find the ID of the element that you need to overlay. Possibly use the demo addon at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Thunderbird?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Extensions%2FThunderbird to get started, although you will most certainly need to overlay a different part of the Thunderbird interface.

Answer (score 0):

The .xul-file will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css"
  href="chrome://YourExtension/content/YourButton.css"?>

<overlay id="YourExtension-overlay"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<script type="application/javascript"
  src="chrome://YourExtension/content/YourButton.js"/>

<toolbarpalette id="MsgComposeToolbarPalette"> // Button available in compose message only
  <toolbarbutton id="your-button-1"/>
  </toolbarpalette>

<toolbarbutton id="your-button-1"
  label="Track"
  tooltiptext="Description by mouseover"
  oncommand="YourJSFunction()"
  class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional YourButton"
  />
</overlay>
```

Want to know more? You can learn how to create a custom button [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Toolbars/Custom_toolbar_button).